# Ошибка отображения контента шаблона Laravel blade на удаленном VPS сервере

Tags: php, laravel, vps

Коллеги, добрый день.
Выгрузил на VPS сервер Laravel проект. На данный момент приложение выдает синтаксическую ошибку "syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file" вот в этом блоке кода:

```
<header class="header py-6">
    <div class="container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center">
        <a class="header__logo" href="/">
            <img class="logo-img" src="/images/logo.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="buttons flex items-center">
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ route('profile.show', Auth::user()->id) }}" class="button__reg font-sans font-normal text-base text-blue-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg px-4 py-2 ml-4  shadow-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">{{ __('В кабинет') }}</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="button__enter font-sans font-normal text-base text-blue-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg px-4 py-2 shadow-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">{{ __('Вход') }}</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="button__reg font-sans font-normal text-base text-blue-500 border border-blue-500 rounded-lg px-4 py-2 ml-4  shadow-md transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">{{ __('Регистрация') }}</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</header>
```

Хотя на локальном Open Server все работает корректно с этим кодом.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Насколько я помню, у `@auth` нет `@else`

Comment: [Authentication Directives](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#authentication-directives).. Вместо `@else` нужно использовать `@guest`

Comment: @guest @endguest?

Comment: Да, если авторизован - `@auth ... @endauth`, если нет - `@guest ... @endguest`